# MySQL 2 queries combine into 1 query - self referencing

Tags: mysql, select, count

We have build a very simple referral system that tracks userID's without cookies and referrals for social media. I am trying to create something like a 'leader board' so I can show the UserID of the top leaders in the database.

I'm trying to combine these 2 queries into 1 query.

```
SELECT
Count(users.AffiliateID) AS affiliate,
users.AffiliateID
FROM
users 
group by affiliateID
order by affiliate desc
```

This generates an output where the variable 'affiliate' contains the USERID of the top referring affiliate.  In this case the #1 person is affiliateID = 5297dc41331235

What I then do is look up the name of the person with this query.

```
Select name from users where UserIDHash = "5297dc41331235";
```

How can I rewrite the query above so that it looks up the value of the name field as a column that references the value of the AffiliateID i.e.  where AffiliateID=UserIDHash on each record?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: to clarify - the system stores a person's UserIDHash value into the AffiliateID field so in pseudo code a line would be   in table users lookup the name where affiliateID=UserIDHash make sense?

Comment: you can `create view` first to create `affiliate` then select in next step;